# Upload XML file in Phalcon

Tags: php, xml, file-upload, phalcon

I am trying to upload XML file to Phalcon application. I was looking for in [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request_File.html) and it does not help me I simply can not get any reaction from upload action below. Like it is not happening.

Here is code from controller:

```
class XmlController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->view->setTemplateAfter('main');
        Phalcon\Tag::setTitle('Xml');
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

    public function uploadAction(){
        if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) { 
            print_r("Yes");
            //Print the real file names and their sizes
            foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file){
                echo $file->getName(), " ", $file->getSize(), "\n";
            }
        }else{
            print_r("No");
        } 

        return $this->forward('xml/');
    }
}
```

Here is code form view (as volt template)

```
 {{ form('xml/upload', 'class': 'form-inline', 'method': 'post') }}
    <span>
        {{ file_field('xml', 'class': 'input-xxlarge', 'style' : 'font-size:15px; height:40px; margin-top: 3px;') }}
        {{ submit_button('Upload XML &raquo;', 'class': 'btn btn-primary btn-large btn-success') }}
    </span>
</form>
```

I am trying to break the ice with simple XML

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
```

What could be happening?
Is there some example of working file upload in phalcon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form:

```
 {{ form('xml/upload', 'class': 'form-inline', 'method': 'post', 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data') }}
```